# Integer arithmetic in Java with char and integer literal

Tags: java

Can someone explain to me why the following code compiles OK in Java?

```
char c = 'a' + 10;
```

Why is this not equivalent to the following, which does not compile?

```
int i = 10;
char c = 'a' + i;
```

The Java Language Specification (section 3.10.1) states "An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type `int` (§4.2.1)." Section 4.2.2 refers to "The numerical operators, which result in a value of type `int` or `long`." So the result of the addition should, in my understanding, be an `int`, which cannot be assigned to the `char` variable `c`.

However, it compiles fine (at least in Sun JDK 1.6.0 release 17 and in Eclipse Helios).

Rather an artificial example perhaps, but it is used in an introductory Java course I have been teaching, and it now occurs to me that I don't really understand why it works.

Comment: Thanks to all who answered. For anyone interested, section 5.2 of the language specification (Assignment Conversion) does in fact say "In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char or int : ... A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable."

Comment: If you, like me, happen to stumble on this because you want to know how to actually convert an indexed char into a string, here you go; when `i=2` then `String.valueOf((char)('a'+i))` returns the String "c".

Comment: The reason is that since `char c` is an unsigned integer is can only take positive values. The compiler is smart enough to understand that `'a' + 10` will never result in an illegal value therefore it compiles. where as the compiler evaluates `'a' + i` in isolation and cant make out if this may result in a negatively signed or positive literal which may be illegal for char and therefore it will complain of lossy conversion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`'a' + 10` is a *compile-time constant expression* with the value of `'k'`, which can initialise a variable of type `char`. This is the same as being able to assign a `byte` variable with a literal integer in [-128, 127]. A `byte` in the range of [128, 255] may be more annoying.

Comment: Thanks. Looking up *compile-time constant expression* led me to the relevant section of the language specification.

Comment: char c = 'a' + 1L does not compile, This is wired

Answer (score 21):

It is because the compiler can check that it (`'a' + 10`) is within the bounds of a char whereas it cannot (in general) check that `'a' + <an integer>` is within the bounds.

Comment: char c = 65535; compiles, but not char c = 65536;

Comment: char is two bytes so this makes sense.

Comment: `char c = 103000;` does not. UCS-2 ftw!

Answer (score 4):

char is actually an unsigned 16-bit integer with a range 0-65535. So you can assign any integer literal in that range to a char, e.g., "char c = 96", which results in "c" holding the character "a". You can print out the result using System.out.println(c).

For the constant expression on the right-hand-side of "char c = 'a' + 10", 'a' is promoted to int first because of the Java numeric promotion rules and the integer value is 96. After adding 10 to it, we get a literal integer 106, which can be assigned to a char.

The right-hand-side of "char c = 'a' + i" is not a constant expression and the expression result assignment rule requires an explicit cast from int to char, i.e., "char c = (char) ('a' + i)".

Answer (score 2):

This code should works:

```
int i = 10;

char x = (char)('a' + i);
```

Answer (score 1):

The constant is of a different type (I know the spec says that `10` should be an int, but the compiler doesn't see it that way).

In `char c = 'a' + 10`, 10 is actually considered a constant variable of type char (so it can be added to a).  Therefore `char c = char + char` works.

In `int i = 10;
char c = 'a' + i;`  You are adding a char to an integer (an integer can be much bigger than a char, so it chooses the bigger data type [`int`] to be the result a.k.a: `'a' + i = int + int`).  So the result of the addition is an integer, which cannot fit into the `char c`.

If you explicitly casted `i` to be a char (e.g.: `char c = 'a' + (char)i;`) it could work or if you did the opposite (e.g.: `int c = (int)'a' + i;`) it would work.

Comment: I don't think it is quite correct to say that 10 is considered to be of type char. Rather, as Tom Hawtin says, the expression `'a' + 10` is a *compile-time constant* and therefore the compiler is allowed to do a narrowing conversion. Actually `char c = 'a' + (char)i;` does not work because the right-hand side is of type `int` and is not a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 0):

According to *Java specification* as of **2020** for widening and narrowing conversions of integral values in expressions:

> "In a *numeric arithmetic context* ...  the promoted type is `int`,
> and any expressions that are not of  type `int` undergo *widening*
> *primitive conversion* to `int`"

In *assignment context*:

> "...if the expression is a *constant expression* of type `byte`,  `short`,
> `char`, or `int`:
>
> • A *narrowing primitive conversion* may be used if the
> variable is of type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the
> *constant expression* is representable in the type of the variable."

So, in `char c = 'a' + 10;` the left constant value is a `char`and the right constant value is `int` fitting into a `char`. While there is an *assignment* and `int` 10 fits into `char`, `int` gets converted to `char`. And the overall result of addition is `char`.

And in `char c = 'a' + i;` (where `int i = 10;`) the `i` is not constant, so, notwithstanding the assignment, the `char 'a'` is promoted to `int` and the overall result is `int`. Thus, the assignment is erroneous without an explicit typecast.

Note, that the following original answer is wrong (it cites treatment in *numeric choice contexts*, like in `switch` statement):

<s>According to *Java specification* for widening and narrowing conversions in expressions:</s>

> If any expression is of type `int` and is not a constant expression,
> then the promoted type is `int`, and other expressions that are not of
> type `int` undergo ***widening** primitive conversion* to `int`.
>
> ...
>
> if any expression is of type `char`, and every other expression is
> either of type 'char' or a *constant expression* of type 'int' with a
> value that is representable in the type 'char', then the promoted type
> is `char`, and the `int` expressions undergo ***narrowing** primitive
> conversion* to `char`.

So, in `char c = 'a' + 10;` the left expression is a `char` and the right constant expression is `int` fitting into a `char`. So, the constant gets converted to `char`. And the overall result is `char`.

And in `char c = 'a' + i;` (where `int i = 10;`) the right expression is not constant, so the the `char 'a'` is promoted to `int` and the overall result is `int`.