# Casting characters in Java

Tags: java

I am learning Java. I found that expressions often have to be cast to a certain type in order to do it right. For example, during arithmetic evaluation, bytes are promoted to integers, so the following expression will throw an error:

```
byte b = 10;
int i;
i = b*b;  //ok, assigning an integer evaluation to an integer variable
b = b*b;  // throws error, coz assigning integer evaluation to byte variable
```

Now, I know that assigning an integer to a character variable is all right: `char a; a = 88;` is okay. However, if I do this:

```
char c2 = 'b', c3 = 'c';
c2 = c2 + c3; //throws error
c2 = (char)(c2 + c3); //works fine
```

Why does it throw an error when not casted? After all, the right hand side is still an integer, so assigning an integer to a character variable should work just fine.

Comment: `88` is a byte, not just an integer

Answer (score 6):

In `c2 + c3`, both operands are implicitly widened to `int`, so the result of the addition is also an `int`.

**[JLS §15.18.2. Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2):**

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

**[JLS §5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):**

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> **Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:**
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.**

You therefore end up with an `int`. Assigning it to a `char` variable requires an explicit cast.

You say:

> Since integer value can be assigned to a character variable...

Only *constant* integer expressions can be assigned to a `char` variable without a cast.

**[JLS §5.2. Assignment Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):**

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

This automatic narrowing conversion doesn't apply here. You need an explicit cast.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I stated. The characters on the right are promoted to integers, thus assigning an integer result to the variable on the left. Since integer value can be assigned to a character variable, why is it throwing an error?

Comment: +1 for the constant thing - I could not find the reference ;-)

Comment: @Cupidvogel: That's not quite correct. Only *constant* integer expressions are narrowed automatically, and here we are not looking at one. I've expanded the answer.

Comment: What exactly is meant by constant expression?

Comment: @Cupidvogel as detailed in the description it is defined in [15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). Basically: a literal, a `final` variable or a combination of literals and final variables.

Comment: But if I do `int i; i = 4.4;` it still throws an error even though it is a constant assignment, whereas if I do `int i; i = 20/6;`, `i` is assigned 3 even though it is not a constant assignment.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: None of this contradicts anything I've quoted from the JLS. Seriously, if you really want to understand the details, read the JLS.

Comment: An expression made up entirely of constant sub-expressions is considered a constant expression.  NPE is right, I've learned a lot from reading (and re-reading) the JLS over the years.

Answer (score 3):

It does not necessarily work fine to assign an int to a char. Chars are only 16 bit and ints are 32 bit, so the there might be an overflow.

In general Java only allows assignment of primitives values without cast if no overflow can occur as a result of the assignment.

Comment: Why would there be an overflow here?

Comment: Simple: Take two of the highest possible char value and add them. That's an overflow. `('\uFFFF' + '\uFFFF') > Character.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: That is a bit of a shortcut. `int i = 1; char c = i;` won't compile although there is no overflow.

Comment: Ummm, because it is not a constant assignment, as explained by NPE below?

Comment: @Cupidvogel Yes exactly. For example `final int i = 1; char c = i;` would compile, because `i` is now a constant.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c2 = 'b', c3 = 'c';
c2 = c2 + c3; //throws error
c2 = (char)(c2 + c3); //works fine
```

when you doing `c2+ c3`

ASCII value of these chars are added which returns a `int` result.
when you are assigning `int` result to `char`  it gives  error.

Comment: That's what I stated, if I do `char c = 99;` it doesn't  throw an error, why here , then?

Comment: char c = 99; 99 is implicitly converted to char. Because at compiler time data type of 99 is known but character arithmetic return type result is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an int 88 to a char works, because the compiler can determine the value.

The case c2 = c2 + c3 cannot be handled by the compiler. The value c2 + c3 must be evaluated at run time. Therefore, the compiler cannot determine the actual char value that has to be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

char is 2 bytes and int is 4 bytes. When you write char c = 1; it does not mean that 1 is int, it's just a constant for javac and javac knows that 1 fits into char. But c2 = c2 + c3; is arithmetic operation, javac will interprets it as `(int)c2 + (int)c3` and this produces int result. int does not fit into char so javac warns you that there may be lost of precision.

Comment: **char is 2 bytes and int is 4 bytes. When you write char c = 1; it does not mean that 1 is int, it's just a constant for javac and javac knows that 1 fits into char.** How can 1 fir into `char` when 1 occupies 4 bytes and char 2 bytes?

Comment: Actually 1 occupies just 1 byte, it is 0x1, and compiler knows that it fits. But if you have int i = 1; char c = i; it won't compile because i is a var it can be longer than 2 bytes

Comment: So you are saying that even though integers have a default space occupancy, integer literals don't abide by that and occupy space ad hoc?

Comment: I mean that in `char = 1` 1 is just an integer constant, `int` is type for local variables, parameters and fields.

Comment: You said that 1 occupies 1 byte, whereas in `int i; i = 1;`, i occupies 4 bytes. Why is that?

Comment: `1` is a constant that needs just one byte - 0x01; but `int` is a 4-byte integer type that is supposed to hold values from 0x80000000 (min) to 0x7FFFFFFF (max)

Comment: Okay, got that. In fact that is what i was trying to ask - that literals occupy space ad hoc. 600000, will, for example, occupy more space, right?

Comment: Right, javac analizes the const size and then decides if it fits into a variable of the given type

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at thread:

[Integer arithmetic in Java with char and integer literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680625/integer-arithmetic-in-java-with-char-and-integer-literal)

The reason seems to be that "c2 = c2 + c3;" cannot be checked by the compiler (it is executed in runtime) whereas "char a; a = 88;" is directly done by the compiler.

Comment: Why is it so? What is the difference between the assignments?

Comment: It is explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2

Comment: It just works like that: if the compiler can convert a numeric value on the fly to byte or char it does it. If the assignment is executed at runtime it follows other paths of conversion. Take it as a handy compiler utility or as an incoherence in the language (whichever you like most ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An example for further clarification:

```
char c1 = Character.MAX_VALUE;
char c2 = Character.MAX_VALUE;
char c3 = (char) (c1 + c2);
int  i3 = c1 + c2;

System.out.printf("After casting to char: %s, the int value: %s%n", (int) c3, i3);
```

So with casting we actually got a wrong mathematical result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a certain limit as to how much value each basic type can hold in java.Assigning the result of an arithmetic operation can produce an unpredictable result at run-time ,which JVM is unsure if char can hold,therefore the compilation error.