# Char array compile time error upon assign a value from array

Tags: java, arrays, char

So I have this code

```
char [] a = {'a','b','c'};

char c = 'a' + 'b'; //works
char c2 = 98 + 97; //works
char c3 = a[0] + a[1]; //compile time error
```

So all of them are the same functionality but upon getting and using an array value it is giving me a compile time error. What is the cause of this??

```
The result of the additive operator applied two char operands is an int.
```

then why can I do this?

```
char c2 = (int)((int)98 + (int)97);
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat it is commented above. I think he is saying that why all of them work but not the array part

Comment: @ScaryWombat Required `char` found `int`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin My eyes must be seriously bad - where is it commented?

Comment: @ScaryWombat `char c3 = a[0] + a[1]; //compile time error`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Sorry I was meaning, what is the wording of the error.  I think that Kick answered me though.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608241/why-cant-you-add-an-int-and-a-char-in-some-cases and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951459/casting-characters-in-java and many others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The result of the additive operator applied two `char` operands is an `int`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands.
>   The type of an additive expression on numeric operands is the promoted type of its operands

The first two are constant expressions where the resulting value is an `int` that can be safely assigned to a `char`.

The third is not a constant expression and so no guarantees can be made by the compiler.

Similarly

> then why can I do this?

```
char c2 = (int)((int)98 + (int)97);
```

That is also a constant expression and the result can fit in a `char`.

Try it with bigger values, `12345` and `55555`.

Comment: for the first sentence, do you have any source? I am sure you right, but I wanna read more about it for myself thank you :)

Comment: @Kick Yes. It's in the JLS, give me a second. I'm on my phone.

Comment: would you please tell me what is JLS as well?

Comment: @KickButtowski it is the java specification language more like the rule book of java

Comment: @kick Which one? Binary numeric promotion is explained in the link.

Comment: @game That is still a constant expression where the result is guaranteed to fit in a char.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what Binary numeric means here? additive expression means + sing?

Comment: @Kick Yes additive op means `+` applied to numeric types. Binary numeric means that two numbers (numeric values) are involved.

Comment: @kick No, _binary_ refers to the fact that `+` applies to **two** values.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so why when we concatenate two strings, we do not end up with int? Is it because String cannot cast to int or vice versa, yet char can be cast to int and vice versa?

Comment: @kick When applied to numeric types, the `+` operator is binary numeric additive operator. When applied to at least one operand of type `String`, it is the string concatenation operator. Please go through the JLS that I've linked.