# want to understand this single line of code

Tags: java

```
int m = 7;
int n = m + 'a' - 'X';
int i = m;

for (; i <= n;) {
    m += i++;
}

System.out.println("i = " + i + " m = " + n + " n = " + m);
```

i do not understand how this line is executed by a compiler 
int n = m + **'a' - 'X'**;

what this line is doing?->**'a' - 'X'**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating with the char variable in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593074/calculating-with-the-char-variable-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

It's taking the ordinal value of the character 'a' - so this is 97 for 'a' and 88 for 'X'.

Note the 'a' is a character, not a string.

You can view the ASCII table here: https://www.asciitable.com/