# I'm confusing about the output of this content

Tags: java, char

I don't understand why the syntax is char d = 'a' + 3; but when printed it out System.out.prinln(d) is d not a + 3. I tried the output and it was unexpected and I don't understand why it print out 'd' because a is char. Can anyone explain for me pls. I'm confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating with the char variable in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593074/calculating-with-the-char-variable-in-java)

Comment: Julia, there are many answers on this question, do any of them explain your question?

Answer (score 0):

The distinction here is in the datatype. A char is a single character, I believe you expected it to function like the String datatype. If `d` was a String it would look like this:

```java
String d = "a" + 3;
System.out.println(d);
```

Output: `a3`

But the code you provided has `d` as a char, which is stored as a whole number following the ASCII table. [image]

In Java a char can be converted to any other of the *integral types*, namely: `long`, `short`, `byte`, and `int`

This means when you can do arithmetic on a char type with an int. Consider:

```java
char a = 'a'; // 'a' has an ASCII value of 97
char d = 'a' + 3;
```

When you add 3 it adds it to the ASCII value of 97. 97 + 3 = 100, which on the ASCII table corresponds to 'd'. This explains your output.

Answer (score 0):

A single character was specified as a type.

'a' is converted to an ascii value. This becomes a value of 97 (see an ASCII table)... then you added 3 to this, so it becomes d. If you print this out it will appear as 'd'

What were you expecting from the output? You might find a string more useful if you are trying to get something like "a 3"

Answer (score 0):

When you add a number to a character in Java, the character gets converted to its corresponding number based on the Unicode system. So, when you have `char d = 'a' + 3;`, the character `'a'` is converted to the number 97 (its Unicode value), and then 3 is added to it. The result, 100, corresponds to the Unicode value of the character `'d'`. So, the variable d ends up storing the character `'d'` itself, not the phrase `"a + 3"`.

When you print d using `System.out.println(d);`, it shows the character value, which is `'d'`.

If you want to print the actual phrase `"a + 3"`, you need to convert the result back to a character or use string concatenation. You can do this this way.

```
   char c = 'a' + 3;
   System.out.println("a + 3 = " + c);
```

Output is: `a + 3 = d`

Answer (score 0):

> *"I don't understand why the syntax is char d = 'a' + 3; ..."*

You are adding *3* to the *[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters)* value of the *char* literal, *a*.
As opposed to appending the number *3* to the letter *a*.

In *Java*, the content within the single-quotation marks is a *char* literal, and not a *String* value.

Here is a relevant excerpt.
*[Primitive Data Types (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)*.

> *"... A literal is the source code representation of a fixed value ..."*
> *"... Always use 'single quotes' for char literals ..."*

As you know, computers use numbers to represent all data; thus the letter *a* is actually mapped to an integer value.
A widely used mapping system called the *ASCII* system, is used by *Java*.

Thus, in *Java*, when you add or subtract an *int* value from a *char*, the *char*'s ASCII value will be resolved.
Thus, *a* + *1* is *b*, and *a* + *2* is *c*, so on and so forth.

> *"... when printed it out System.out.prinln(d) is d not a + 3. ..."*

The *[println](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String))* method is going to print a value, and not a *[statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)*.

If you wanted to print out the entire statement, you'd have to supply the actual text.

```java
System.out.println("'a' + 3");
```

> *"... I tried the output and it was unexpected and I don't understand why it print out 'd' because a is char. ..."*

I believe you have the variable name *d*, and it's actual value *"d"* mixed-up.
The *println* method was printing the value of *d*, and not the variable name, *d*.

For example, consider the following.
This will print *"xyz"*, and not *"abc"*.

```java
String abc = "xyz";
System.out.println(abc);
```

Output

```
xyz
```