# Integer arithmetic with character

Tags: java

I have a simple block of code, can someone explain to me why this acceptable in Java?

```
int a = 10;
int c = 'A' + (a -1);
System.out.println(c);
```

The result of this displayed in compiler is: **74**.
So where exactly the values of seventies come from? 
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Try `System.out.println((int)'A')`

Comment: see https://www.asciitable.com/ 65 + 10 -1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer arithmetic in Java with char and integer literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680625/integer-arithmetic-in-java-with-char-and-integer-literal)

Answer (score 5):

In Java a `char` can be (explicitly or implicitly) casted to `int`, it then uses the ASCII value associated to this character.

It your case, the seventies comes from the character `'A'`. The ASCII value of this character is `65`. So the system implicitly does the casting `'A' → 65`. Your calculation does:

```
c = 'A' + (a-1)
 ↓
c = 65 + (10-1)
 ↓
c = 74
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. I didn't know that characters can be implicitly converted into Int type.

Answer (score 2):

The `ascii` value of `'A'` is 65. Check this [link](https://www.asciitable.com/) for complete reference. The conversion occurs through (implicit) widening the char datatype to int datatype using its unicode value, which in this case for `'A'` is 65 ([jls 5.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1)).

Comment: Maybe also explain *why* `'A'` is a valid integer

Comment: Added some info.

Answer (score 0):

Char is implicitly converted into integer resulting 'A' = 65 
so 65+9 = 74

Answer (score 0):

When you assign value of one data type to another, the two types might not be compatible with each other. It should be casted to correct type:

There are 2 types:-

- Widening or Automatic Type Conversion. 
  which casts in this sequence:

> byte -> short -> int -> long -> float -> double
>
> char -> int

example :

```
int i = 100; //i is 100
float f = i; // f is 100.0
```

- Narrowing or Explicit
  Conversion. which casts in this sequence:

> double -> float -> long -> int ->short -> byte

example:

```
double d = 100.100; //d is 100.100
int i = (int)d; //i is 100
```

So, When a Character value is used in integer context. It is automatically casted to int.
In your case:

```
int a = 10;
int c = 'A' + (a -1); //c = 65 + (10-1)
```

'A' ascii value is 65, thus you get c = 74

Hope this helps.