# Something doesnt work with my code to get a Number of checksums

Tags: java, methods

this Method is supposed to check the checksums from a Start to an endvalue, if the checksum is equal with a number of your choice, increment counter. So far everything looks fine but somhow the variable checksum in the second for loop gives out a number between 49 and 57 everytime. while the first 3 digits in the variable oneDigit is correctly 1 then 0 then 2 so it should give me 1 + 0 + 2 = 3.

i want to start with public static void häufigkeitDasQuersummeTeilbarDurch (102,999, 3) as example

```
public class MathCalculation {
    
    public static void häufigkeitDasQuersummeTeilbarDurch (int startvalue, int endvalue, int numberWichChecksumShouldEqual) {
        int i = startvalue;
        int counter = 0;
        
        for(;i<=endvalue;i++) {
            int digitLength = String.valueOf(i).length();
            int checksum = 0;
            
            for( int j = 0; j < digitLength; j++ ) {
                checksum = 0;
                char oneDigit = String.valueOf(i).charAt(j);
                checksum += oneDigit;
                
            }
            if(checksum == numberWichChecksumShouldEqual) {
                counter += 1;
            }
            
            
        }
        
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you reset `checksum` inside your `j-for-loop` ?

Comment: `charAt` will return the Unicode codepoint of the character at that place. If you know it's good old `0`-`9` then you can just subtract `'0'` from it. Alternatively you could use [`Character.getNumericValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)).

Comment: i reset it so i can get the next checksum sum :) i dont want it to be counted alltogether

Comment: When you add `oneDigit` to `checksum`, `oneDigit` will be casted to int using the ASCII value of this char as an int. So `'1'` will be casted to `49`

Comment: @Joachim Sauer , but if i print the chars out in the forloop it gives me the correct values inside the char

Comment: That's because you're probably using `println(char)` which takes that Unicode codepoint and prints the character it represents. Try printing it using `System.out.println((int) oneDigit)` to see the actual numeric value stored in `oneDigit`. Note that [U+0030](https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+0030) is the digit `0` (i.e. decimal 48). And the other digits are upwards from there.

Comment: Please see : [Integer arithmetic with character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078054/integer-arithmetic-with-character)

Comment: @DavidRumpf `checkcum` should be reset inside the `i-loop` (which you did). But not a second time in the `j-loop` (which you should correct)

Comment: ah yeeah, i corrected that, thy :) 

@Joachim Sauer, getnummericvalue worked just fine, thanks