# counting alphabetic characters between 'a' and 'z'

Tags: java, char

I came across a code which checks whether a character is between 'a' and 'z' case insensitive. However, I don't understand what the line after that is doing which is:

```
alphabets[c - 'a']++;
```

Could someone please explain this code to me?

```
alphabets = new int[26];
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')
    {
        alphabets[c - 'a']++; // what does this do?
    }
}
```

Comment: the answer to this is tied to the answer to the question "what is a `char` in Java?".

Comment: Above code counts occurrence of each alphabet in given string. alphabets[c - 'a']++; increments the count.

Comment: so when you are subtracting two characters, does it compare the ascii value? And so what if you get a negative value ?

Comment: This brings us back to [what is a `char` in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), which leads to things like https://stackoverflow.com/a/3680665/740553 - As for negative numbers, if `('a'<c && c<'z')` then any code that follows can't yield negative numbers.

Comment: re: "whether a character is between 'a' and 'z' case insensitive".  There's nothing case-insensitive about the posted code.  It counts characters between 'a' and 'z' and ignores everything else, including 'A' to 'Z' -- i.e., it treats lowercase and uppercase differently, and is therefore case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code counts the number of times every lower-case letter appears in the strings. `alphabets` is an array where the first (i.e., index `0`) index holds the number of `a`s, the second the amount of `b`s, etc.

Subtracting `a` from the character will produce the relative index, and then `++` will increment the counter for that letter.

Comment: understood! Can we ever get a negative ascii value?

Comment: The line before hand ensures you only do this for characters between `a` and `z`, so you can never get negative index.

Comment: ```char``` is an unsigned integral type, so although ```'a' - 'b'``` is equal to -1, that will be treated as 65535 (0xffff) by the usual rules of arithmetic of unsigned numbers.  Generally speaking, there's no reason why such numbers are not valid characters (note that Java uses Unicode, not ASCII), although 0xffff in particular is a reserved value that is ["not a character"](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

A `char` in Java is just a small integer, 16 bits wide.  Generally speaking, the values it holds are the values that Unicode [aside: Java does not represent characters as "ASCII"] assigns to characters, but fundamentally, chars are just integers.  Thus `'a'` is the integer `0x0061`, which can also be written as `97`.

So, if you have value in the range 'a' to 'z', you have a value in the range 97 to 122.  Subracting 'a' (subtracting 97) puts it in the range 0 to 25, which is suitable for indexing the 26-element array `alphabets`.